# Java Stack Overflow Error

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I'm trying to program a GCD algorithm and everything seems to be correct except the StackOverflowError. Here is the code:

```
public class Gcd {
    public static BigInteger gcdNaive(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
        int res = a.compareTo(b);

        if ( res == 0 ) {
            BigInteger g = a;
            return g;
        }
        else if ( res == 1 ) {
            BigInteger h = a.subtract(b);
            a = h;
            return gcdNaive(a, b);
        }
        else if ( res == -1 ) {
            BigInteger g = b.subtract(a);
            b = g;
            return gcdNaive(a, b);
        }

        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    }

    public static BigInteger gcdEuclid(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
        if( b == BigInteger.ZERO ) {
            BigInteger g = a;
            return g;
        }
        else if ( b != BigInteger.ZERO ) {
            BigInteger g = b;
            BigInteger h = a.mod(b);
            a = g;
            b = h;
            return gcdEuclid(a, b);
        }

        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError 


    at Gcd.gcdNaive(Gcd.java:7) 
    at Gcd.gcdNaive(Gcd.java:19)
```

Comment: What inputs produce the error?

Comment: The entirety of your second function can be replaced by `return b == BigInteger.ZERO ? a : gcdEuclid(b, a.mod(b));` You're returning values from paths that should never be reached, and making your code unnecessarily hard to follow with all these temporary variables.

Comment: Well, have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for gcdNaive is:

```
public static BigInteger gcdNaive(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    int res = a.compareTo(b);

    if(res == 0)
    {
        return b;
    }

    if(res == 1)
    {
        a = a.subtract(b);
        return gcdNaive(a, b);
    }
    else
    {
        b = b.subtract(a);
        return gcdNaive(a, b);
    }
}
```

The complete solution for gcdEuclid is

```
public static BigInteger gcdEuclid(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {

    if(b == BigInteger.ZERO)
    {
        return a;
    }

    return gcdEuclid(b, a.mod(b));
}
```